# How to find the height of an object via it's shadow

Tags: geometry

I cannot figure out this geometry problem even though it seems like a 3rd grade problem. I'm sorry if this question embarasses you. Anyways..

See the figure below.

[image]

My known values are $d$, $t$, and $s$. I would like to know how high an object is above the ground, by measuring its shadow, $s$, and also the horizontal distance between the object and the beginning of the shadow, $t$. Finally, $d$ is the diameter of the object. Consider this object to be a perfect sphere.

Please note that there is an error in measuring this way, as the light does not necessarily cast a shadow from the bottom and the top of a round object. I am neglecting this error as I am considering the point of light to be far far away.

How do I find the height, $h$, of the object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the light source is very far (e.g. the Sun) then you can consider the rays as parallel, so that in your picture you have two similar triangles and $t:h=(t+s):(h+d)$. From that you easily get $d=(h\cdot s)/t$

Comment: Yeah I should have used my assumption. :D

Comment: I'm sorry again. I don't see how you get that equality. If t:h = (t+s):(h+d), doesn't that mean h/t = (t+s)/(h+d), which means we get an equation with an h^2 term?

Comment: From $t:h=(t+s):(h+d)$ you get $(h+d):h=(t+s):t$ and then $d:h=s:t$.